# Write a url path parameter to a query string parameter in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a place name from a url path into a query string on nginx.

I want `ourdomain.com/hotels/london?some_key=value` to become `ourdomain.com?d=london&some_key=value`

We were doing it with Apache -

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?\??(.*)$ ?d=$1&$2 [QSA]
```

And we're currently doing on haProxy (acting as a reverse proxy) -

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /hotels/([^/\ \?]+)/?\??([^\ ]*)(.*)$     \1\ /?d=\2&\3\4
```

How do I do the same thing on nginx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
rewrite ^/hotels/([^/]+)/?$ /?d=$1 permanent;
```

The `nginx` URI always has a leading `/`. The `?` and query string is not part of the normalised URI, but the `rewrite` directive appends any arguments automatically unless there is a trailing `?`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.